# Java 8 streams, lambdas

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to learn how to utilize Java 8 features(such as lambdas and streams) in my daily programming, since it makes for much cleaner code.

Here's what I am currently working on:
I get a string stream from a local file with some data which I turn into objects later. The input file structure looks something like this:

```
Airport name; Country; Continent; some number;
```

And my code looks like this:

```
public class AirportConsumer implements AirportAPI {

List<Airport> airports = new ArrayList<Airport>();

@Override
public Stream<Airport> getAirports() {
    Stream<String> stream = null;
    try {
        stream = Files.lines(Paths.get("resources/planes.txt"));
        stream.forEach(line -> createAirport(line));

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return airports.stream();
}

public void createAirport(String line) {
    String airport, country, continent;
    int length;


    airport = line.substring(0, line.indexOf(';')).trim();
    line = line.replace(airport + ";", "");
    country = line.substring(0,line.indexOf(';')).trim();
    line = line.replace(country + ";", "");
    continent = line.substring(0,line.indexOf(';')).trim();
    line = line.replace(continent + ";", "");
    length = Integer.parseInt(line.substring(0,line.indexOf(';')).trim());
    airports.add(new Airport(airport, country, continent, length));
    }
}
```

And in my main class I iterate over the object stream and print out the results:

```
public class Main {



public void toString(Airport t){
  System.out.println(t.getName() + " " + t.getContinent());
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Main m = new Main();
    m.whatever();

}

private void whatever() throws IOException {
    AirportAPI k = new AirportConsumer();
    Stream<Airport> s;
    s = k.getAirports();
    s.forEach(this::toString);

}


}
```

My question is this: How can I optimize this code, so I don't have to parse the lines from the file separately, but instead create a stream of objects Airport straight from the source file? Or is this the extent in which I can do this?

Comment: Note: you should close the file: `try(Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(...)) { lines.map(xxx).collect(...) };`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to use [`map()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) to transform the data as it comes past.

```
Files.lines(Paths.get("resources/planes.txt"))
     .map(line -> createAirport(line));
```

This will return a `Stream<Airport>` - if you want to return a `List`, then you'll need to use the `collect` method at the end.

This approach is also stateless, which means you won't need the instance-level `airports` value.

You'll need to update your createAirport method to return something:

```
public Airport createAirport(String line) {

    String airport = line.substring(0, line.indexOf(';')).trim();
    line = line.replace(airport + ";", "");
    String country = line.substring(0,line.indexOf(';')).trim();
    line = line.replace(country + ";", "");
    String continent = line.substring(0,line.indexOf(';')).trim();
    line = line.replace(continent + ";", "");
    int length = Integer.parseInt(line.substring(0,line.indexOf(';')).trim());
    return new Airport(airport, country, continent, length);
}
```

If you're looking for a more functional approach to your code, you may want to consider a rewrite of `createAirport` so it doesn't mutate line.  Builders are also nice for this kind of thing.

```
public Airport createAirport(final String line) {
    final String[] fields = line.split(";");
    return new Airport(fields[0].trim(), 
                       fields[1].trim(), 
                       fields[2].trim(), 
                       Integer.parseInt(fields[3].trim()));
}
```

Throwing it all together, your class now looks like this.

```
public class AirportConsumer implements AirportAPI {

    @Override
    public Stream<Airport> getAirports() {
        Stream<String> stream = null;
        try {
            stream = Files.lines(Paths.get("resources/planes.txt"))
                                   .map(line -> createAirport(line));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            stream = Stream.empty();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return stream;
    }

    private Airport createAirport(final String line) {
        final String[] fields = line.split(";");
        return new Airport(fields[0].trim(), 
                           fields[1].trim(), 
                           fields[2].trim(), 
                           Integer.parseInt(fields[3].trim()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Provided that the `createAirport` method is changed to `return` the created airport instead of appending it to that (now obsolete) list.

Comment: As an addition I would recommend to read the [java.util.stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#package.description) package description. It's not very long and really helpful to understand the streams.

Comment: I'm talking about mutation of the reference.  The `line` passed in does not have the same value as `line` half-way down the method.

Comment: Absolutely fantastic answer, thank you so much!

EDIT: Actually sorry, it gives me 2 errors.
1 is that it cannot resolve method stream() and the second one gives me an error trying to pass the string line to createAirport().

Comment: the second error is as follows: createAirport (java.lang.String) in AirportConsumer cannot be applied to (<lambda parameter>)

Comment: Your `try(…)` statement will close the stream before it is returned, that’s surely not what you want. The try-with-resources construct is only useful for resources you are processing within the scope of the statement, not when you want to return the resource to the method’s caller. Btw., I don’t get why you name a class which *produces* `Airport` instances `AirportConsumer`.

Comment: Damn, you're absolutely right.  Good catch.  However, once the contents of the file have been converted to airports, the file could be closed while leaving the stream open.

Comment: But that’s not how streams work. All intermediate operations are lazy and are performed when the sink (aka terminal operation) requires another element. Hence, the last line will be `map`ped to an `Airport` instance right before the terminal operation processes the last element (if it ever does, as it might be short-circuiting). So there is no place where all lines have been converted already but keeping the stream open would make sense.

Answer (score 0):

The code posted by Steve looks great. But there are still two places can be improved:
1, How to split a string.
2, It may cause issue if the people forget or don't know to close the stream created by calling getAirports() method. So it's better to finish the task(toList() or whatever) in place.
Here is code by [abacus-common](https://github.com/landawn/abacus-common)

```
try(Reader reader = IOUtil.createBufferedReader(file)) {
    List<Airport> airportList = Stream.of(reader).map(line -> {
        String[] strs = Splitter.with(";").trim(true).splitToArray(line);
        return Airport(strs[0], strs[1], strs[2], Integer.valueOf(strs[3]));
    }).toList();
} catch (IOException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

// Or By the [Try](https://cdn.rawgit.com/landawn/AbacusUtil/master/docs/Try_view.html):

```
List<Airport> airportList = Try.stream(file).call(s -> s.map(line -> {
    String[] strs = Splitter.with(";").trim(true).splitToArray(line);
    return Airport(strs[0], strs[1], strs[2], Integer.valueOf(strs[3]));
}).toList())
```

Disclosure： I'm the developer of abacus-common.